# Welcome message by Telegram Bot in group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a group on telegram and I want to welcome everybody who joins that group by a message. For that I have created a Bot and added it to my group. Is there any way I can make bot respond to new joining of group.

I have added a description welcome message to Bot but that only shows up when I go to personally chat the bot.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive `new_chat_members` instead of `text` in [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) update.

And you can send welcome when received that :)

Answer (score -2):

you can use the Welcome bot for Telegram

Here is the GitHub repo for that [Welcome Bot](https://github.com/jh0ker/welcomebot)

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking about adding that feature to their own bot and not using another bot.